# Meaning of "top addresses"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

In the context of hotels what is the meaning of addresses?

> The guide has been produced in association with Nespresso, a fitting
>   alliance given the company’s coffee machines enhance the guest
>   experience at so many of Australia’s top addresses.

I would like to know a detailed answer to the meaning of address in this context. Is it a resort? entertainment place? a hotel? or simply a destination?

From an article entitled: [Gourmet Traveller publishes guide to nation’s 50 best hotels](http://magazines.org.au/news/gourmet-traveller-publishes-guide-to-nations-50-best-hotels)

Comment: It's just a pretentious way of saying "places"--could be hotels, casinos, offices, private homes, any place you might find an overpriced espresso machine coupled with premeasured coffee.

Comment: @StoneyB "addresses" is just a pretentious way of saying "places". "Top" means "best".

Answer (score 3):

"Top addresses" means "best locations".

Most of the time that "top addresses" is used, it means "most prestigious locations".  For example, Donald Trump builds and promotes his buildings so that people will be proud to mention their address at "Trump Tower" or "Trump Plaza".

In the original poster's example, "top addresses" is a kind of flattery.  The author is claiming that many prestigious hotels use Nespresso coffee machines.  If this is true, then the statement is true.  However, if most hotels that use Nespresso coffee machines are not prestigious, then the statement is flattery.